# Show Last Record only if Condition Met

Tags: crystal-reports

My report needs to show the last record of a client *only* if certain conditions are met. But I also need to still show a client who hasn't met those conditions.

The report currently shows clients that have been coded with `303` (only the last time) and those that haven't. But those that aren't `303` shouldn't show anything.

```
Client    Date          Process Code  

4         4/1/2017      303        
4         5/1/2017      101       
4         6/1/2017      303         

6         4/1/2017      101
6         6/3/2017      101

7         5/15/2017     303
7         5/28/2017     101
```

What they want to see on the report is:

```
Client      Date           Process Code
4           6/1/2017       303
6    
7           5/15/2017      303
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a group for your `client`
- Sort the records within that group by `date` descending (don't sort the group itself)
- Print client details in detail block
- Suppress details block if `process code` is not `303` or one detail row has already been printed

  - Add an additional Detail section *after* the existing one(s). Suppress it if you want to.
  - Place a formula `@printed` in the added Detail section, containing something like

    ```
    shared BooleanVar printed303; 
    if {Yourtable.ProcessCode = 303 then printed 303 := true;
    ```
  - Place another formula `@reset` in the group header containing something like

    ```
    shared BooleanVar printed303; 
    printed303 := false;
    ```
  - Add a Suppress Condition to your detail section containing somthing like

    ```
    shared BooleanVar printed303; 
    {Yourtable.ProcessCode <> 303  or printed303;
    ```

That should do what you described.

Comment: How do I write that out?

Comment: in my header i have shared stringvar := " ";  Then for my formula I declare the var and then say that if the code equals 303 to print the date and put it in the footer but it doesn't seem to find the previous 303s. so have someone who had a 303 on June 1 but then another code on June 3 and it appears blank

Comment: It suppressed all my details

Comment: @isoman4not5 Add the formula where you set printed to true in an additional detail section, *after* the detail section(s) you want to print. You may suppress this section - it just makes sure that the formula is evaluated after printing the detail sections you want.

Comment: I missed the part about the extra details section. That got it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make shared variables that store the relevant fields when your Process Code = `"303"`.

Whenever you change groups, reset the variables back to "". (You can do this by placing a formula in Client's Group Header.) Display these in your Client Group Footer with new formulas. If any `303`'s were found, the variables will display the latest value they captured. Otherwise, blank.

Comment: I got that far but I'm still not sure how to show that last 303 code

Comment: Tried that. I have Group 1 - Staff Member, Group 2 - Client No, Group 3 - Date, Group 4 - Process Code. I had to do that because the clients can have more than one process on a given date.  Still can't get it to do what I want.

Comment: @isoman4not5 Which sections are unsuppressed? I would think you'd want every section suppressed except for Group 2's footer.

Comment: Everything but 4

Comment: @isoman4not5 Try putting everything you want to display in the Group Footer of Group 2, and unsuppress that. (You can suppress 4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147750/discussion-between-4444-and-isoman4not5).